# Unable to redirect to my Tomcat application after Keycloak login

Tags: java, tomcat, keycloak

after configuring my Tomcat Application, and the Keycloak-Tomcat connector, I am trying to make Keycloak login work.
When I enter my application main page(localhost:8081/PowerApp), the keycloak login page appears. After I log in, the browser displays this error: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS, and apparently, there is an infinite loop in the communication between Keycloak and my application (please, you may find attached a screenshot of this communication).

I hace configured my Tomcat adapter by adding this to my web.xml (apart from creating the context.xml):

```
(...)
<security-constraint>
<display-name> constraint for the roles folder </display-name>
<web-resource-collection>
<web-resource-name> PowerApp main</web-resource-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint>
<role-name>DRIVER</role-name>
<role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
(.....)
```

In the administration console, I have configured this parameters inside my client:
Valid redirect URI: http://localhost:8081/PowerApp/*

Thank you very much.
[communication flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaOlq.png)

Comment: Hola! I'm not using the tomcat adapter (but the spring security one), but it seems the application doesn't recognize you're already logged in (because the adapter tries to redirect you to the keycloak login again). Try to enable the keycloak adapter logs (org.keycloak namespace) to see what's going on.

Comment: Hi! Could you tell me how can I do that? I'm pretty new with Keycloak :)

Comment: That depends on which library you're using in tomcat to display the application logs. You need to modify the configuration in order to get the keycloak logs displayed. Then, you'll be able to see the behaviour ;-)

Comment: Any luck in solving this issue?